# What is the covariance of a sum and a double sum?

Tags: statistics, summation, covariance

can someone please explain what the covariance of the following is?

$$
\text{Cov}\big(\sum_{i}^{m}{X_{ik}},\sum_{k}^{o}\sum_{i}^{m}{X_{ik}}\big)
$$

In [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Covariance.html) it says

$$
\text{Cov}\big(\sum_{i}^{m}{X_{i}},\sum_{j}^{n}{Y_{j}}\big) = \sum_{i}^{m}\sum_{j}^{n}{}\text{Cov}\big(X_{i},Y_{j}\big)
$$

but each RV is being summed once. What if one is being summed twice?

Thanks

Comment: What if you call $Y_{km} = \sum \limits_i^m X_{ik}$? Could you apply the linearity result twice?

Comment: @Max I tried using your hint and wrote out the steps in an answer below. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}\Big(\sum \limits_i^m X_{ik} , \sum \limits_v^o \sum \limits_t^m X_{tv} \Big) & = \text{Cov}\Big(\sum \limits_i^m X_{ik} , \sum \limits_v^o \sum \limits_t^m X_{tv} \Big) \\
 & = \text{Cov}\Big(\sum \limits_i^m X_{ik} , \sum \limits_v^o Y_{mv} \Big) \\
& = \sum \limits_i^m \sum \limits_v^o \text{Cov}\big(X_{ik},Y_{tm}\big)\\
& = \sum \limits_i^m \sum \limits_v^o \text{Cov}\big(X_{ik},\sum \limits_t^m X_{tv} \big)\\
& = \sum \limits_i^m \sum \limits_v^o \sum \limits_t^m\text{Cov}\big(X_{ik}, X_{tv} \big)\\
\end{align}
$$

[1]  Using the hint from @Max.
[2]  Use the left-hand side of identity (18) with the right-hand side of identity (21) from [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Covariance.html).
[3]  Replace substitute variable with original value.
[4]  Use the right-hand sides of identity (18) and (21) from Wolfram.

Comment: Might $\sum \limits_i^m \sum \limits_j^o \sum \limits_h^m\text{Cov}\big(X_{ik}, X_{hj} \big)$ be less ambiguous?

Comment: @Henry Done. I used t,v instead of h,j.